# How to clean the project from generated files using build_runner

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I'm using `MobX` for my flutter project and it needs `build_runner` to generate related files, now I have hundred auto-generated files, now I want to remove them all, What command can lean my project from these files?

I'm using following command to generate the files:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

By saying auto-generated files I mean files with this formats: `*.g.dart`, `*.inject.summary` , ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not find a valid solution, so I used `bash` to remove mentioned files using this command and use it on terminal:

```
find . -maxdepth 20 -type f \( -name "*.inject.summary" -o -name "*.inject.dart" -o  -name "*.g.dart" \) -delete
```

You can also add it to the aliases: (and use by typing `rmAll` command in terminal)

```
alias rmAll='find . -maxdepth 20 -type f \( -name "*.inject.summary" -o -name "*.inject.dart" -o  -name "*.g.dart" \) -delete'
```

You can add your favorite file type by adding it's extension before the second parenthesis by this format:  `-o -name "*.XXX"`

Answer (score 6):

A solution that works for me

```
flutter pub run build_runner clean
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

try running this and when files are deleted ctrl c/option c to interrupt building. works for me

Answer (score -3):

You can try this, It's work for me

```
flutter clean

flutter build ios
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't care about `*.inject.dart`, `*.inject.sammary`, `*.g.dart` files.

Comment: flutter clean: won't clean the generated files *.g.dart
nor the flutter build ios would generate them 